# Can you change CSS3 animation keyframe attributes inline (i.e. in the HTML style attribute)?

Tags: html, animation, css

Is it possible to change the animation keyframe attributes by making inline adjustments.

Take for example

```
@-moz-keyframes slidein {
    from {
        width: 10%;
    }

    to {
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to change the width attribute in the 'to' portion of the keyframe, by doing something like

```
<div id="someID" style="change keyframe here">
```

For the time being I am just creating an entire style sheet dynamically on the page in order to customize the keyframes.

This method works, however I would much rather adjust the attributes inline for simplicity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. since the animation is not **declared** in the element, it's only **called** upon it. It's like trying to add methods into an object instead of to a class. Not possible, sorry ;)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll stick to my current method then.

Comment: A nitpick: since we are in the Web environment, it makes perfect sense to add a method into a Javascript object...

Comment: I'm confused... what about the accepted answer? it works.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a way to do this using CSS variables:

```html
<div style="--from-width:10px; --to-width:20px; animation:slide 1s ease infinite;"></div>
```

```css
@keyframes slide {
  from {
    width: var(--from-width);
  }

  to {
    width:var(--to-width);
  }
}
```

That obviously won't work for all cases, but if you just need to customize some numbers in an existing set of keyframes, then it may work for you.

Comment: It helped me a lot using several variables to mimic a complete class. Thanks! :)

Comment: +1 _This_ should be the accepted answer (or, at least, the highest ranked answer) - not the ES5 answer from Oct 2011 and certainly not the _"Not possible"_ answer from Jul 2011.

Answer (score 20):

Hey so lets think a little different... You may not be able to do this...

```
<div id="someID" style="change keyframe here">
```

but think of doing it like this...

```
<script>
var createdStyleTag = document.createElement("style");
createdStyleTag.textContent = "@-*whatevaVendor*-keyframes someAnimationName{"+
    "from { width: **SOMETHING YOU DECLARE THROUGH JS**; }"+
    "to{ width: 10%; }"+
"}";

document.body.appendChild(createdStyleTag);
</script>
```

This is pretty open to whatever you want to do... you would always have the classes you will put on elements but sometimes we dont want to constantly have the same "from" and "to" so this can be one way to do this... basically you dynamically create a style element put whatever string that will end up being the needed style text and then append it to the body... works pretty good... used it in my own framework... I don't do it exactly like this but I wrote it out like this for visibility... reason why this works in a good way is cause a lot of my DOM is created dynamically as well so it may make more sense in that implementation...

Nothing is impossible... just think outside the div

Comment: Ah, I just implemented this to find Mozila arnt supporting it ;
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=830056
Annoyingly they dont seem to think its a problem either.
@benny Any chance you could go into details with your answer? It flew quite over my head and I need an alternative, thanks.

Comment: @darkflame - here in the future, it works okay with `@-moz-...` but I don't think prefixes are needed much nowadays so I replaced `@-*whatevaVendor*-keyframes` with just `@keyframes`, and it works great (for my needs anyway).

Answer (score 6):

I was searching for a solution for inline keyframe too. At least for the "to" value.
CSS Tricks give a good solution, just forget the "to" and place the width inline ;)
http://css-tricks.com/animate-to-an-inline-style/

Answer (score 0):

This solution sounds a lot like the one you may already be implementing, but it's very well explained and thought out:
[Set Webkit Keyframes Values Using Javascript Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342494/set-webkit-keyframes-values-using-javascript-variable)

Answer (score -1):

as @Zetura said the best way to do it is to forget the "to" property and it will take the default value of the width or height or any thing you put it to the 
as example for me its work :

```
@keyframes slideInUp {
    0% {
        height: 0px;

    }

}
```