# Changing the different Keyframes in css using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, animation, css-animations

I'm creating a small website that tells a story by using css and sprite animation.

The problem I'm encountering is that I do not know how to change the keyframes once I have set them in the css files expecially while I try to make it compatible with all of the browsers.

Here is what I have,

the main part of the css:

```
#ManSprite{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:280px;
    left:140px;
    background-image: url("http://imageshack.com/a/img571/1710/2r1h.png");
    z-index:99;
    animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -moz-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -ms-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -o-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}
```

Then in my javascript I would like to change the background position for every keyframe but I'm not sure how to change it. I've tried the following but it does not work.

```
var StoryPart = 0;

var fromArray = new Array("0px", "-200px", "-800px", "-1400px", "-2200px", "-3200px");
var toArray = new Array("0px", "-600px", "-1400px", "-2200px", "-3230px", "-4000px");
var stepsArray = new Array(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4);


function nextBtn() {
    StoryPart++;

    startChange();

}

// begin the new animation process
function startChange() {
    // remove the old animation from our object
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.webkitAnimationName = "none";
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.animationName = "none";
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.msAnimationName = "none";
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.oAnimationName = "none";
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.mozAnimationName ="none";

    // call the change method, which will update the keyframe animation
    setTimeout(function () { change("play", fromArray[StoryPart], toArray[StoryPart]); }, 0);
}


// search the CSSOM for a specific -webkit-keyframe rule
function findKeyframesRule(rule) {
    // gather all stylesheets into an array
    var ss = document.styleSheets;

    // loop through the stylesheets
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {

        // loop through all the rules
        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {

            // find the -webkit-keyframe rule whose name matches our passed over parameter and return that rule
            if (ss[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE && ss[i].cssRules[j].name == rule
                || ss[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE && ss[i].cssRules[j].name == rule
                )
                return ss[i].cssRules[j];
        }
    }

    // rule not found
    return null;
}

// remove old keyframes and add new ones
function change(anim, fromValue, toValue) {
    // find our -webkit-keyframe rule
    var keyframes = findKeyframesRule(anim);

    // remove the existing 0% and 100% rules
    keyframes.deleteRule("0%");
    keyframes.deleteRule("100%");

    // create new 0% and 100% rules with random numbers
    keyframes.insertRule("0% {background-position: " + fromValue + ";}");
    keyframes.insertRule("100% {background-position: " + toValue + ";}");

    // assign the animation to our element (which will cause the animation to run)
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.webkitAnimationName = anim;
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.animationName = anim;
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.msAnimationName = anim;
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.oAnimationName = anim;
    document.getElementById('ManSprite').style.mozAnimationName = anim;

}
```

For some reason in Chrome, it doesn't find any cssRule inside the findKeyframesRule method, but in firefox it does. Firefox crashes, however, on this line

```
keyframes.insertRule("0% {background-position: " + fromValue + ";}");
```

which confuses me because it was able to use deleteRule well.

Anyone ever work with these?

Comment: If those values you are trying to set are not dynamic, then I’d rather put them into different stylesheet rules in the first place, and just switch between the applied rules by changing f.e. the class of the element(s) with JS.

Comment: @CBroe so you mean create multiple plays,play1,play2,etc and just use the different values I have stored?

Comment: following post might have an answer you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342494/set-webkit-keyframes-values-using-javascript-variable

Comment: @webdev-dan already checked that. I'm no longer having the MAIN problem, the problem I am having now is insertRule not working in firefox for some reason.

Comment: never used this ...but as i noticed in docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule )
insertRule needs 2 arguments - like this: `keyframes.insertRule("0% {background-position: " + fromValue + ";}", keyframes.cssRules.length);`

Comment: Yea sadly I've used that too and it doesn't work. The weird thing is that in chrome it works.