# change css keyframes value via jquery

Tags: jquery, css

everytime the screensize changes i want to change a keyframe value:

Css:

```
.wave {
      animation: wave 2s cubic-bezier(0.53, 0.63, 0.45, 0.36) infinite;
    }

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100px; /*<<<<i want to freely change this value*/
  }
}
```

Is there a jQuery option to change "margin-left: -100px;" to "margin-left: -200px" ?

Comment: https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342494/set-webkit-keyframes-values-using-javascript-variable

Comment: I dont understand how to replace key frame values from the documentation Axel. And the answer you provided dosnt have a working example anymore disinfor, does it still work somehow like this? what do i need to change to get it working nowadays?