# Passing parameters to css animation

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

```
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

For the animation CSS code above, I'm wondering whether there's any way to pass the values of `margin-left` and `width` as parameter from Javascript.

Comment: Not sure if you can do it directly but what you could do is set a css variable with javascript and then use this variable in your `@keyframes`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use CSS variables and you can easily do this:

```js
document.querySelector('.p2').style.setProperty('--m','100%');
document.querySelector('.p2').style.setProperty('--w','300%');
```

```css
.p1,.p2 {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: var(--m, 0%);
    width: var(--w, 100%);
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">
 This will not animate as the animation will use the default value set to the variable
</p>
<p class="p2">
  This will animate because we changed the CSS variable using JS
</p>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work (atleast for me) if the position of the <p> (or <div>) is set to relative

Answer (score 2):

Maybe another way to do this is to use: [Element.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

```js
var m = "100%";
var w = "300%";

document.getElementsByClassName('p2')[0].animate([{
        marginLeft: m,
        width: w
    },
    {
        marginLeft: '0%',
        width: '100%'
    }
], {
    duration: 2000,
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1">
 This will not animate as the animation will use the default value set to the variable
</p>
<p class="p2">
  This will animate because we changed the CSS variable using JS
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Temani Afif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750566/16444630), But one animation is removed so it is easy to understand what is going on .

Use CSS variables and you can easily do this:

```js
document.querySelector('.p2').style.setProperty('--m','100%');
```

```css
.p1,.p2 {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: var(--m, 0%);
   
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">
 This will not animate as the animation will use the default value set to the variable
</p>
<p class="p2">
  This will animate because we changed the CSS variable using JS
</p>
```

Comment: I don't see what this answer is adding to the question. Did you read it? you simply removed one part of my answer. I don't see what *simplification* you did since you are using the exact same technique

Comment: I meant, it was difficult for me to understand your answer when i first read it because there are two variables changing at the same time . This is not your fault and I am grateful of your answer, but I thought if I removed one animation, then it would be a lot simpler for the readers to understand what is going on.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I should have said that it is your answer without the scaling effect (as it is now) , but instead I wrote it as "similar to Temani Afif's answer ". My mistake.

Comment: Maybe the reason for me finding it difficult to understand what is going on is because I'm new to css and javascript.