# How do you dynamically add keyframes through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, web, dom

So , I want to animate an Html element using a variable through keyframes , I am unable to find a way to do it through DOM.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="pawn" id="pawn1"></div>
```

CSS keyframes code

```
@keyframes mov_pawn_up {
    0% {
        bottom: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom: 700%;
    }
}
```

Here , I want to be able to change the `bottom` property using a variable.

Thank you.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750473/passing-parameters-to-css-animation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS variables. Basic idea below

```js
const board = document.querySelector(".board");
const root = document.documentElement;

const update = (evt, y) => {
  const piece = evt.target;
  piece.classList.remove("active");
  piece.style.bottom = y + "px";
};

board.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const clicked = evt.target.closest(".piece");
  if (!clicked) return;
  const startY = Number(clicked.dataset.y);
  const endY = startY - 20;
  
  root.style.setProperty('--bottom-0', startY + "px");
  root.style.setProperty('--bottom-100', endY + "px");

  clicked.removeEventListener('animationend', update);
  clicked.addEventListener('animationend', evt => update(evt, endY));
  clicked.dataset.y = endY;
  
  clicked.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
:root {
  --bottom-0: 0px;
  --bottom-100: -0px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

span.piece {
  position: relative;
}


span.piece.active {
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: mov_pawn;
}

@keyframes mov_pawn {
    0% {
        bottom: var(--bottom-0);
        color: blue;
    }
    100% {
        bottom: var(--bottom-100);
        color: black;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <span class="piece" data-y="0">X</span>
  <span class="piece" data-y="0">X</span>
  <span class="piece" data-y="0">X</span>
  <span class="piece" data-y="0">X</span>
</div>
```