# CSS : How to pass animation time and `@keyframe` values from function?

Tags: html, css, angular, animation, keyframe

I am working in angular and in that, I am giving animations to text.
But here I want to set dynamic time for animation.

For example: Here I have created class `.slide-in-top` in `CSS` and set animation time to `1.3s` but I want to set it from function `addAnimation()` like If I want to set it `2, 3 or 4 seconds` as I want.

And also I want to set that `keyframes` values which is currently set `transform: translateY(-40px)` here `-40px` I have set static but I want to set it from `addAnimation()` function as I want like `-30px or-50px` etc.

```js
addAnimation();

function addAnimation(){
 $("#user_text").addClass('slide-in-top');
}
```

```css
.slide-in-top {
  -webkit-animation: slide-in-top 1.3s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  animation: slide-in-top 1.3s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 20px; background:#0095ff;height:100px;padding:20px">
  <p id="user_text">This is Animated text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using css or scss ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya I am using `css`

Comment: why you don't use something like this?
 `var time=5; $("#user_text").addClass('slide-in-top').css({'animation-duration':time+'s'});`

Comment: @RohitTagadiya, And for setting value for `@keyframes` visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342494/set-webkit-keyframes-values-using-javascript-variable. hop it help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are expecting.

Using `setParameters('1.3s','-50px')` function you can set animation duration and keyframes values transform property dynamically.

```js
function addAnimation(animationName,animationStyles){

 let styleElement = document.createElement('style');
 styleElement.type='text/css';
 document.head.appendChild(styleElement); 
 let styleElementSheet = styleElement.sheet;
 styleElementSheet.insertRule(`@keyframes ${animationName}{
 ${animationStyles} }`,styleElement.length);
 
 styleElementSheet.insertRule(`@-webkit-keyframes ${animationName}{
 ${animationStyles} }`,styleElement.length);
}

function setParameters(animDuration,translate){
 $("#user_text").addClass('slide-in-top');
document.getElementsByClassName('slide-in-top')[0].style.animation = `slide-in-top ${animDuration} cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both`;


addAnimation('slide-in-top', `
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(${translate});
    transform: translateY(${translate});
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`);
}
setParameters('1.3s','-50px'); //change this based on u r requirements
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 20px; background:#0095ff;height:100px;padding:20px">
  <p id="user_text">This is Animated text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write the code like this

```js
function addAnimation(from, to){
  $( "#user_text" ).css('margin-top', from);
  $( "#user_text" ).css('opacity', '0');
  $( "#user_text" ).animate({
      "margin-top": to,
      "opacity": 1
    }, 1500 );
}

addAnimation("-30px", "0px");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 20px; background:#0095ff;height:100px;padding:20px">
  <p id="user_text">This is Animated text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid mixing JQuery and Angular. It could lead to potential scaling up issues down the road. Instead you could try to use [Angular animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations). You could pass dynamic values using interpolation binding.

Try the following

animate-text.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { state, trigger, style, animate, transition, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'animate-text',
  template: `
  <div style="margin-bottom: 20px; background:#0095ff;height:100px;padding:20px">
    <p *ngIf="show" [@keyframes]="{value: '', params: {duration: duration, translateStart: translateStart}}">This is Animated text</p>
  </div>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('keyframes',[
      transition('void => *', [
        animate('{{ duration }} cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940)', keyframes([ 
          style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY({{ translateStart }})'}), 
          style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0px)'})
        ])),
      ])      
    ])
  ]
})
export class AnimateText {
  @Input() duration: string = '1.3s';
  @Input() translateStart: string = '-40px';
  show: boolean = true;

  onMouseUp() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  Default (duration: 1.3s, translateY: -40px):
  <animate-text></animate-text>

  duration: 3s, translateY: -30px:
  <animate-text duration='3s' translateStart='-30px'></animate-text>

  duration: 10s, translateY: 80px:
  <animate-text duration='10s' translateStart='80px'></animate-text>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I've made the **animate-text.component.ts** to accepts two inputs `duration` and
`translateStart`. They act as the dynamic values for animation duration and `translateY` value at keyframe 1.

The values are passed to the animation definition using the `params` property of the value bound to the animation property `[@keyframes]="{value: '', params: {duration: duration, translateStart: translateStart}}"`. Notice the use of interpolation in the animation definition to use the values

- **duration** - `animate('{{ duration }} cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940)`
- **translateStart** - `style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY({{ translateStart }})'})`

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-keyframes-dynamic-values-9gjpoc)