# How can I escape/inline/cheat to get around <style> tag filtering in XWiki?

Tags: html, css, xwiki

I'm using an instance of XWiki which is filtering out `<style>` tags, meaning that the following:

```
<style>
    p { color: red; }
</style>

<p>Foo</p>
```

Would have the `<style>` tag completely removed upon rendering, resulting in just:

```
<p>Foo</p>
```

I am able to do inline styles, using the following syntax:

```
(% style="color: red;" %)
<p>Foo</p>
```

But my issues arises when I'm trying to use animation keyframes. I know they can be done inside of a style tag:

```
<style>
@keyframes stomp {
    0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(1deg); }
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
</style>
```

But I don't know how to inline that, since the `<style>` tag will be removed by XWiki.

My question: How do I either...

1. inline the keyframes into an element style (I don't believe this can be done, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510094/can-you-change-css3-animation-keyframe-attributes-inline-i-e-in-the-html-style) is pretty old)?
2. obfuscate the `<style>` tag so that it's not stripped?

Answer (score 0):

The style tag is not supposed to go in the body of the HTML (at least not in [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#edef-STYLE)). All the HTML you are inserting inside the {{html}} macro in a wiki page's content goes into the HTML's body. That's why the HTML cleaner might be filtering/removing your content.

You should check out and understand the proper way of adding JavaScript and CSS to your wiki pages in XWiki, through [JavaScriptExtensions](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Tutorials/SkinExtensionsTutorial/#HMinimalJavaScripteXtension) or [StyleSheetExtensions](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Tutorials/SkinExtensionsTutorial/#HMinimalStyleSheeteXtension). More generally, try to avoid inlining. It's considered a bad practice and hardly justified in practice.

If you really must have the style tag inside the HTML's body, you can instruct the {{html}} macro to avoid automatic cleaning by using the [clean="false" parameter](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/HTML%20Macro#HParametersdefinition).

Example:

```
{{html clean="false"}}
<style>
  ...
</style>
{{/html}}
```

However, I recommend you use the above only for testing purposes and use proper JavaScript/Style Extensions for the final version.